# My react app is getting hang when I insert long space middle of the input value after crossing the input limit. I set the input limit using regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Input field component.I create this component to validate the form.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
    import { randomKey } from "cm-apptudio-ui/Utility/Utility";
    
    
    const TextBox = (props) => {
      var type = props.type || "text";
      var validate = null;
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <input
            type={type}
            id={props.id || randomKey()}
            className={
              props.isRequired ? props.className + " required" : props.className
            }
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            disabled={props.disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
            readOnly={props.readOnly}
            style={props.style}
            onChange={(e) => {
              props.onChange(e);
    
              if (e.target.value) {
                e.target.classList.remove("alert-danger", "validation");
                e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = "";
              }
    
             
            }}
            onBlur={(e) => {
              const value = props.value;
    
              if (!props.isRequired) return true;
              if (props.isRequired) {
                if (props.isRequired && !value) {
                  let flag = e.target.classList.contains("alert-danger");
                  if (flag) {
                    e.target.classList.add("alert-danger", "validation");
                  }
                  e.target.classList.add("alert-danger", "validation");
                  e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = "Field Is Required";
                  if (props.onValid) props.onValid(id, "required");
                  return;
                } else {
                  let flag = e.target.classList.contains("alert-danger");
                  e.target.classList.remove("alert-danger", "validation");
                  e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = "";
                  if (props.onValid && flag) {
                    props.onValid(id, "");
                  }
                }
              }
    
              if (value) {
                var regex2 = /^\s*$/;
                if (regex2.test(value)) {
                  e.target.classList.add("alert-danger", "validation");
                  e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText =
                    props.errorMessage || "Invalid input";
                  return;
                }
              }
    
              if (props.pattern) {
                var regex = RegExp(props.pattern);
                if (!regex.test(value)) {
                  e.target.classList.add("alert-danger", "validation");
                  e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText =
                    props.errorMessage || "Invalid input";
                  return;
                }
              }
            }}
            value={props.value}
            ref={props.ref}
            autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
          />
    
          <span style={{ color: "red" }} className="help-block text-danger"></span>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default TextBox;
```

And I use this input field component in a form. this component accepts regex and validates the input value and set the input limit. when I cross the input limit and insert a long white space meddle of the value my app got hang.

```
                 <TextBox
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    isRequired={true}
                    disabled={this.state.disabledInput}
                    errorMessage="Pattern does not match"
                    pattern="^(?:[ ?a-zA-Z\-\_][\s\r\n]*){0,300}$"
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={(evt) => this.changeHandler(evt)}
                    value={this.state.firstName}
                    id="firstName"
                    ref="firstName"
                    autoComplete="nope"
                  />
```